# Synonym für "in der [Örtlichkeit]"

Tags: synonym

Ich suche ein Synonym für *in der*. Beispiel:

> Das Event findet *in der* Brauerei statt. Anschließend gibt es einen Empfang *in der* Gaststätte.

Oder kann man die beiden Sätze irgendwie geschickter zusammenfassen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ein Synonym fällt mir nicht ein, vielleicht so umformulieren:

> Das Event findet in der Brauerei statt. Für den [sich] anschließenden Empfang haben wir die Gaststätte [aus]gewählt / vorgesehen / reservieren lassen.

Oder so:

> Das Event findet in der Brauerei statt. Für den [sich] anschließenden Empfang steht uns die Gaststätte zur Verfügung.

Comment: ... und tausend andere Formulierungen. - *Das Event findet in der Brauerei statt. Danach laden wir Sie zu einem Imbiss **in die** Gaststätte.*